# Detecting IEnumerable "State Machines"

Tags: c#, api-design

I just read an interesting article called [Getting too cute with c# yield return](http://www.daedtech.com/getting-too-cute-with-c-yield-return)

It made me wonder what the best way is to detect whether an IEnumerable is an actual enumerable collection, or if it's a state machine generated with the yield keyword.

For example, you could modify DoubleXValue (from the article) to something like:

```
private void DoubleXValue(IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    if(points is List<Point>)
      foreach (var point in points)
        point.X *= 2;
    else throw YouCantDoThatException();
}
```

Question 1) Is there a better way to do this?

Question 2) Is this something I should worry about when creating an API?

Comment: You should use an interface rather than a concrete and also cast lower down, `ICollection<T>` would be a better choice as not all collections are `List<T>`. For example, arrays `Point[]` implement `IList<T>` but are not `List<T>`.

Comment: Welcome to the problem with mutable types. Ienumerable is implicitly supposed to be an immutable data type, so mutating implementations are violation of LSP. This article is a perfect explanation of the dangers of side effects, so practice writing your C# types to be as side effect free as possible and you never need worry about this.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa `IEnumerable` is immutable in the sense that you can't modify a collection (add/remove) while enumerating it, however if the objects in the list are mutable, it's perfectly reasonable to modify those while enumerating the list.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I disagree. If the collection is expected to be immutable, the expectation from a consumer is that the members will not be mutated by outside actors, that would be called a side effect and violates the immutablility expectation. Violates POLA and implictly LSP.

Comment: How about using `ToList`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx It doesn't detect whether it was generated by yield, but instead it makes it irrelevant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your question, as I understand it, seems to be based on an incorrect premise. Let me see if I can reconstruct the reasoning:

- The linked-to article describes how automatically-generated sequences exhibit a "lazy" behaviour, and shows how this can lead to a counter-intuitive result.
- Therefore I can detect whether a given instance of IEnumerable is going to exhibit this lazy behaviour by checking to see if it is automatically generated.
- How do I do that?

The problem is that the second premise is false. Even if you could detect whether or not a given IEnumerable was the result of an iterator block transformation (and yes, there are ways to do that) it wouldn't help because the assumption is wrong. Let's illustrate why.

```
class M { public int P { get; set; } }
class C
{
  public static IEnumerable<M> S1()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
      yield return new M { P = i };
  }

  private static M[] ems = new M[] 
  { new M { P = 0 }, new M { P = 1 }, new M { P = 2 } };
  public static IEnumerable<M> S2()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      yield return ems[i];
  }

  public static IEnumerable<M> S3()
  {
    return new M[] 
    { new M { P = 0 }, new M { P = 1 }, new M { P = 2 } };
  }

  private class X : IEnumerable<M>
  {
    public IEnumerator<X> GetEnumerator()
    {
      return new XEnum();
    }
    // Omitted: non generic version
    private class XEnum : IEnumerator<X>
    {
      int i = 0;
      M current;
      public bool MoveNext()
      {
        current = new M() { P = i; }
        i += 1;
        return true;
      }
      public M Current { get { return current; } }
      // Omitted: other stuff.
    }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<M> S4()
  {
    return new X();
  }

  public static void Add100(IEnumerable<M> items)
  {
    foreach(M item in items) item.P += 100;
  }
}
```

All right, we have four methods. S1 and S2 are automatically generated sequences; S3 and S4 are manually generated sequences. Now suppose we have:

```
var items = C.Sn(); // S1, S2, S3, S4
S.Add100(items);
Console.WriteLine(items.First().P);
```

The result for S1 and S4 will be 0; every time you enumerate the sequence, you get a fresh reference to an M created. The result for S2 and S3 will be 100; every time you enumerate the sequence, you get the same reference to M you got the last time. **Whether the sequence code is automatically generated or not is orthogonal to the question of whether the objects enumerated have referential identity or not.** Those two properties -- automatic generation and referential identity -- actually have nothing to do with each other. The article you linked to conflates them somewhat.

Unless a sequence provider is documented as always proffering up objects that have *referential identity*, it is unwise to assume that it does so.

Comment: We all know you will have the correct answer here, that's a given; but if you could put a little more definition into the term "referential identity" it might be good, I am reading it as "immutable" but that's because I conflate immutable in C# with new object returned every get or value type, which I think is the same thing you're referring to. Though granted immutability can be had in a variety of other ways, it's the only rational way in C# (that I'm aware of, you may well know ways I'm unaware of).

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Two object references x and y have "referential identity" if Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) returns true.

Comment: Always nice to get a response straight from the source. Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 10):

I think the key concept is that you should treat any `IEnumerable<T>` collection as *immutable*: you shouldn't modify the objects from it, you should create a new collection with new objects:

```
private IEnumerable<Point> DoubleXValue(IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    foreach (var point in points)
        yield return new Point(point.X * 2, point.Y);
}
```

(Or write the same more succinctly using LINQ `Select()`.)

If you actually want to modify the items in the collection, don't use `IEnumerable<T>`, use `IList<T>` (or possibly `IReadOnlyList<T>` if you don't want to modify the collection itself, only items in it, and you're on .Net 4.5):

```
private void DoubleXValue(IList<Point> points)
{
    foreach (var point in points)
        point.X *= 2;
}
```

This way, if someone attempts to use your method with `IEnumerable<T>`, it will fail at compile time.

Comment: The real key is like you said, return a new ienumerable with the modifications when you want to change something. Ienumerable as a type is perfectly viable and has no reason to be changed, it's just the technique for using it needs to be understood as you said. +1 for mentioning how to work with immutable types.

Comment: Somewhat related - you should also treat every IEnumerable as if it is done via deferred execution.  What may be true at the time you retrieve your IEnumerable reference may not be true when you actually enumerate through it.  For example, returning a LINQ statement inside a lock can result in some interesting an unexpected results.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I agree.  I go a step further and try to avoid iterating over an `IEnumerable` more than once.  The need to do so more than once can be obviated by calling `ToList()` and iterating over the list, though in the specific case shown by the OP I prefer svick's solution of having DoubleXValue also return an IEnumerable.  Of course, in real code I would probably be using `LINQ` to generate this type of `IEnumerable`.  However, svick's choice of `yield` makes sense in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, I didn't want to change the code too much to make my point. In real code, I would have used `Select()`. And regarding multiple iterations of `IEnumerable`: ReSharper is helpful with that, because it can warn you when you do that.

Answer (score 6):

I personally think the problem highlighted in that article stems from overuse of the `IEnumerable` interface by many C# developers these days. It seems to have become the default type when you're requiring a collection of objects - but there's a lot of information that `IEnumerable` simply doesn't tell you... crucially: whether or not it has been reified*.

If you find that you *need* to detect whether an `IEnumerable` is truly an `IEnumerable` or something else, the abstraction has leaked and you're probably in a situation where your parameter type is a little too loose. If you require the extra information that `IEnumerable` alone doesn't provide, make that requirement explicit by choosing one of the other interfaces such as `ICollection` or `IList`.

**Edit for the downvoters**
Please go back and read the question carefully. The OP is asking for a way to ensure that `IEnumerable` instances have been materialized before being passed to his API method. My answer addresses that question. There is a wider issue regarding the proper way to use `IEnumerable`, and certainly the expectations of the code the OP pasted are based on a misunderstanding of that wider issue, but the OP did not ask how to correctly use `IEnumerable`, or how to work with immutable types. It's not fair to downvote me for not answering a question which was not posed.

* *I use the term `reify`, others use `stabilize` or `materialize`. I don't think a common convention has been adopted by the community just yet.*

Comment: One problem with `ICollection` and `IList` is that they are mutable (or at least look that way). `IReadOnlyCollection` and `IReadOnlyList` from .Net 4.5 solve some of those problems.

Comment: Please explain the downvote?

Comment: I disagree that you should change the types you're using. Ienumerable is a great type and it can often have the benefit of immutability. I think the real problem is people don't understand how to work with immutable types in C#. Not surprising, it's an extremely stateful language, so it's a new concept to many C# devs.

Comment: Only ienumerable allows deferred execution, so disallowing it as a parameter removes one whole feature of C#

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I think the downvote is pretty unfair. I'm certainly not disputing the usefulness of `IEnumerable` at all. What I'm saying is, asking for a way to tell if an `IEnumerable` is using deferred execution is asking for a leaky abstraction. My answer is basically the same as svicks, did you downvote that too?

Comment: Don't take it personally, you're answer shows you understand many things but the first 2 sentences in svick's answer are the correct answer in my opinion, and your answer is simply not correct as it doesn't relate a correct understanding of ienumerable, rather it seems to simply say you should use other types if you're unsure. I also disagree that people are overusing ienumerable, rather people are using it the right amount but not with the right techniques, you don't mention the right way to use ienumerable, @svick does.

Comment: It doesn't matter anyway, when eric lippert weighs in on a question related to this stuff everyone else's answers are just noise :P

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I don't think it's in the spirit of Stack Exchange to downvote answers like this. By all means upvote the answers which you would like to see bubble to the top, but it's difficult not to take it personally when someone downvotes you after you've gone to the time & trouble to try and help. This happens a lot to me and it's really starting to make me think twice about bothering to write any answers at all.

Comment: I down voted it because I think it's wrong. I think that is in the spirit of SE, to ensure people don't put stock in incorrect information it is up to all of us to down vote those answers. Maybe I'm wrong, totally possible that I'm wrong and you're right. That's up to the broader community to decide by voting. Sorry you're taking it personally, if it's any consolation I've had many negative voted answers I've written and summarily deleted because I accept the community thinks it's wrong so I'm unlikely right.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I think you're getting confused between "incorrect" and "not how I would do it". While you may not have taken the same approach, the OP was asking for a way to tell if a collection had been materialized - switching to another interface such as `ICollection` achieves that goal. The ironic thing is that I totally agree with your approach and that's how I would approach the problem too, but that doesn't mean that alternative solutions are wrong.